# Bind data in to a data table in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, html-table

I have some data inside a script which needs to be arranged in a data table. I have no idea how to achieve this as I am a fresher and still learning.

The data is in :

```
<script>
        var $textarea = $('#TextArea1'), $submit = $('#Submit1');
        $submit.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            sourceCode = $textarea.val();
            var $searchObject = $('<div id="Searching"></div>');
            $searchObject.append($(sourceCode));

            alert("Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of textbox = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is " + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Telephone entry fields = " + $searchObject.find('[type=tel]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=tel]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of Telephone entry field button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Password boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=password]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=password]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of Password box = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of check boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=checkbox]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Radio buttons on page = " + $searchObject.find('[type=radio]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=radio]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of radio button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of drop down lists = " + $searchObject.find('select').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=select]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of select button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Images on page = " + $searchObject.find('img').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=img]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of Image = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Hyperlinks on page = " + $searchObject.find('a[href]').length);

            alert("Number of Buttons     = " + $searchObject.find('[type=button]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=button]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));

            });
            alert("Number of Date entry fields= " + $searchObject.find('[type=date]').length);
            $searchObject.find('[type=date]').each(function () {
                alert("Name of date button = " + $(this).attr("name") + " and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id"));
            });     
        });
    </script>
```

I want to bind this data in to a data table and display it in the web page instead of showing them as alert popups. The data needs to be arranged in the table under

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Element </th>
      <th>Element name</th>
      <th>Element ID</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What will be the best method to achieve this? Can anyone please help me out with the code to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear with what are you asking? You want to create datatable from script's data? If so, why don't you write code in code behind and create datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <textarea id="TextArea1"></textarea>
      <button id="Submit1">submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var $textarea = $('#TextArea1'), $submit = $('#Submit1');
            $submit.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                sourceCode = $textarea.val(); 
                var $searchObject = $('<div id="Searching"></div>');
                $searchObject.append($(sourceCode));

              var table = $('<table border="1"></table>');
                table.append("<tr><td colspan='2'>Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length+"</td></tr>");

                $searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function () {
                    table.append("<tr><td>Name of textbox = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> and its ID is " + $(this).attr("id")+"</td></tr>");
                });

              table.append("<tr><td colspan='3'>Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length+"</td></tr>");
                $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                    table.append("<tr><td>Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> and its ID is =" + $(this).attr("id")+"</td></tr>");
                });

              //Added remaining code here

              table.appendTo($(this).parent());        
            });
    });
</script>
```

Found the script to add data to tables. Tnx to http://forums.asp.net/members/raju%20dasa.aspx